# what is the equation to get this type of a curve?

Tags: functions

[image]

what must be the equation to get this type of a curve??

the curve must increase from -infinity to 0 and then decrease again to +infinity.

Thank you

Comment: Such a curve is not algebraic: those are by definition given by polynomials and intersect each line (or other curve) in finitely many other points by Bézout.. That is clearly not the case in your picture..

Comment: (There used to be a tag "algebraic-curves")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try multiplying a $\sin$ wave with a Gaussian, e.g:
$$\sin(5x)e^{-x^2/2}$$
 [image]

Comment: Related: [Gabor filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabor_filter), [Morlet wavelet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morlet_wavelet).

Answer (score 0):

y=sin(x)/x  has this property.
sin(x)/x function has a special name: sinc(x)
It is an important function. For example it is the Fourier transform of the rectangular pulse which plays a major role in signals and systems analysis.

Comment: The sine cardinal is an even function, while the OP's function does not at all look even...

Comment: @J.M. I don't think the OP wants the function to be even. I mean if he wanted the function in the figure then how did he plot it?

Comment: Still, the graph of the function you propose looks nothing like the OP's picture...